# htaccess code for language and slug

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, slug, lang

I'm trying to handle language and slug through my htaccess but I'm having some issues.

What I need is to turn this:

```
http://www.domain.com/es/product/lorem-ipsum
```

into this:

```
http://www.domain.com/product.php?lang=es&slug=lorem-ipsum
```

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngineOn
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(es|fr)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ product.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But this is what I'm getting in product.php $_GET

```
Array
(
    [lang] => 'es'
    [slug] => 'lorem-ipsum/product/lorem-ipsum'
)
```

********** UPDATE ***********

If I change the first rule for this:

```
RewriteRule ^(es|fr)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [R]
```

It works fine, but my URI changed for this:

```
http://www.domain.com/product/lorem-ipsum?lang=es
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(es|fr)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /product.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching all characters

```
(.*)
```

much just the letters like this

```
([a-zA-Z].*)
```

Comment: The slug may contain digits, so this is not a valid answer for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter then add the digits: `([a-zA-Z0-9].*)` isn't hard

Comment: I know, but that's not going to solve the duplicated slug. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter since the regex isn't matching the slash char it should work

Comment: It takes no effect. The @Croises solution works like a charm. Thanks anyway.